# Demonstrate that every positive integer can be expressed as the sum of distinct non-negative integer powers of 2

Tags: proof-writing, induction, proof-explanation, solution-verification

**Demonstrate that every positive integer can be expressed as the sum of distinct non-negative integer powers of 2. In other words, prove that for every positive integer can be re-written as $2^{b_0}+2^{b_1}+...2^{b_r}$ such that $b_0\lt b_1\lt...b_r$**

**I'm not sure if I'm doing this right** but so far this is what I have:

**Base Case:** n=1, which can be written as $2^0=1$. Assume that for some integer $k\ge 1$, $k$ can be written as $2^{b_0}+2^{b_1}+...2^{b_r}$. We will demonstrate that $k+1$ can be written as the sum of distinct powers of $2$.

**Case 1:** $k+1$ is odd

$k+1=2^0+k$; since k is already a sum of distinct powers of 2, for any odd number $k+1$ the claim is true.

**Case 2:** $k+1$ is even

Since $k+1$ is even, then $\frac{k+1}{2}$ is an integer which is also strictly less than k. By applying the inductive hypothesis, $\frac{k+1}{2}\le 2^{b_0}+2^{b_1}+...2^{b_r}$. Multiplying 2 on both sides, we get $k+1=2^{b_0+1}+...2^{b_r+1}$

Since for both conditions the claim is held true, it is true that for any integer n, it can be written as a sum of distinct powers of 2

**Uhhh** I'm quite certain that I've made some sort of mistake because I'm not jiggy with this proof

I'm not really satisfied with my explanation for case 1 - I'm more confident about case 2.

I'm also just ***assuming*** that for all numbers less than k the claim is true which I feel is some sort of logical flaw?

Answer (score 2):

This is (essentially) a correct argument. You are using what's known as *strong induction* when you assume the inductive hypothesis for all previous cases, not just the immediately previous case.

See https://undergroundmathematics.org/glossary/strong-induction

Note: you are proving that every positive integer has a  base $2$ representation.